# Обрезание текста в Pandas и замена обрезанного троеточиями

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется следующий код:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.width', 10000)  
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)


df = pd.read_excel("body/tabl.xlsx")   
text = df.loc[(df['Наименование ОС и тип аппаратной платформы'] == 'Windows') & (df['Идентификатор'] == 'BDU:2014-00001') & (df['Вендор ПО'] == 'Schneider Electric')]
print(text)
```

Вывод при этом следующий:

```
Идентификатор                            Наименование уязвимости  ...           Вендор ПО Наименование ОС и тип аппаратной платформы
0  BDU:2014-00001  Уязвимость микропрограммного обеспечения прогр...  ...  Schneider Electric                                    Windows

[1 rows x 5 columns]
```

Я пробовал без опций для ширины текста и количества столбцов, т.е. с таким кодом:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel("body/tabl.xlsx")   
text = df.loc[(df['Наименование ОС и тип аппаратной платформы'] == 'Windows') & (df['Идентификатор'] == 'BDU:2014-00001') & (df['Вендор ПО'] == 'Schneider Electric')]
print(text)
```

И тогда получался немного другой вывод:

```
Идентификатор  ... Наименование ОС и тип аппаратной платформы
0  BDU:2014-00001  ...                                    Windows

[1 rows x 5 columns]
```

Как можно получить текст без обрезания и/или содержимое одной ячейки в таблице?

Answer (score 1):

В итоге, я нашёл метод в котором задействуются три параметра, и это мне помогло.
Сами параметры:

```
# Сброс ограничений на количество выводимых рядов
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
# Сброс ограничений на число столбцов
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
# Сброс ограничений на количество символов в записи
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)# Установите для отображения самой большой линии
```